# How to get an adwords account client customer id to link it to a MCC account?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I'd like to add an Adwords account to a MCC account via Google Adwords API on my web application.
I guess I just need to add a [ManagedCustomerLink](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/ManagedCustomerService.ManagedCustomerLink)

The thing is I don't know how to get *clientCustomerId*.
I thought by authenticating the user via OAuth2 on my application with the matching scope, I could somehow get their  *clientCustomerId* but I could not find it.

Thank you by advance for your help !

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. Where are you trying to do this? Are you adding an account in MCC, or are you coding?

Comment: I am coding this on an application, so a user who wants to be linked to the application MCC account just needs to sign in with Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the client customer id by running the next code:

```
CustomerServiceInterface customerService = adWordsServices.get(session, CustomerServiceInterface.class);
Customer[] customers;
try {
    customers = customerService.getCustomers();
    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        Long customerId = customer.getCustomerId();
        System.out.println(customerId);
    }
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In order to get the user session you have to use Oauth 2.0 and ask for his credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading your exchange with George Astonishing above, I wonder if you really want to add AdWords accounts to your MCC.

There is a difference between an AdWords account owner

1. Authorizing your app to access their data, vs
2. Becoming your company's client for full AdWords management.

If this AdWords account belongs to your company's client, and you are taking over their account management, then you can use [ManagedCustomerService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/ManagedCustomerService) to add the account to your MCC.  You can get the account's 10-digit AdWords Customer ID using [CustomerService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/CustomerService).

On the other hand, if this is for a web app, and you just want users to be able to authorize with OAuth2, then you should follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) instead.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. If I use the _CustomerService_, I only get the MCC account. 

Basically, I just want a convenient way for a user on my web application to link their AdWords Account to my MCC account (this is your bulletpoint 2. ). How can I get someone's 10-digit AdWords Customer ID ? I thought I could get it by making then sign in to the application. (your bulletpoint 1.).

Sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: Is the account you want to link currently under the management of a different MCC?

Comment: No. It could be, but let's assume it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here, visit this link to Google Adwords library,

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201509/AccountManagement/GetAccountHierarchy.php

Once you create a new user

```
   $user = new AdWordsUser(); // with your API creds using OAUTH       
   GetAccountHierarchyExample(AdWordsUser $user)  //found in link
```

Just run the function. It will list all your managed subaccounts.

Comment: So tried doing this, but it is asking me for client customer Id to do even this...

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code you can get your client customers

```
public Customer[] GetAllManagerClientsList(string authorizationCode)
        {
            string baseURL = _configuration.GetValue<string>("URL:SiteURL");
            AdsOAuthProviderForApplications oAuth2Provider = (user.OAuthProvider as AdsOAuthProviderForApplications);
            oAuth2Provider.Config.OAuth2RedirectUri = baseURL + "/google-auth-callback";

            oAuth2Provider.FetchAccessAndRefreshTokens(authorizationCode);

            //Get customerID
            user.Config.OAuth2AccessToken = oAuth2Provider.Config.OAuth2AccessToken;
            user.Config.OAuth2RefreshToken = oAuth2Provider.Config.OAuth2RefreshToken;
            //store in cache
            var chechedEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));


            CustomerService customerService = (CustomerService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201809.CustomerService);
            var customersList = customerService.getCustomers();

            var ClientCustomers = customersList != null && customersList.Length > 0 ? customersList.Where(c => c.canManageClients == false).ToList() : null;
            if (ClientCustomers.Count() > 0)
            {
                return ClientCustomers.ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```