# Adwords API getting customerId

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I have an adwords user's Oauth credentials, and I'm able to successfully make an API call to download a report, but I had to hard-code in the customerId as I couldn't figure out how to get it.

The get() method of the [CustomerService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201409/CustomerService) in the API should return the customer ID, but what are the parameters to pass to it?

I tried a GET request to [this URL](https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/mcm/v201409)
 without any header params or body params, to which it returns:

```
 "<html><body>No service was found.</body></html>".
```

I also tried with an Authorization and developerToken defined in the headers, but got the same response.

I also tried the [python library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib), and defined an instance of AdWordsClient like this, but it's client_customer_id variable ends up as None:

```
from googleads.adwords import AdWordsClient

oauth_client = GoogleRefreshTokenClient(environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'), environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'), oauth_record.refresh_token)
adwords_client = AdWordsClient(environ.get('ADWORDS_DEVELOPER_TOKEN'), oauth_client, user_agent='agent'))
customer_id = adwords_client.client_customer_id
print 'customer_id:' + str(customer_id)
```

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463918/how-to-get-an-adwords-account-client-customer-id-to-link-it-to-a-mcc-account), I don't care about adding the user to my MCC account.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get the customer ID with the googleads-python-lib library:

```
oauth_client = GoogleRefreshTokenClient(environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'), environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'), oauth_record.refresh_token)
adwords_client = AdWordsClient(environ.get('ADWORDS_DEVELOPER_TOKEN'),  oauth_client, user_agent='your_user_agent_here')
customer = adwords_client.GetService('CustomerService').get()
customer_id = customer['customerId']
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this in 2020?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from googleads import oauth2, adwords

oauth_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, refresh_token)
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(ADWORDS_DEVELOPER_TOKEN, oauth_client, user_agent='your_user_agent')
customers = adwords_client.GetService('CustomerService', version='v201809').getCustomers()
print(customers['customer_id'])
```

Comment: This example doesn't work anymore (can't import 'adwords')